# Struts：JSPのhtml:checkboxで、初期値でチェックを入れた状態にしたいです。

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts

JSP の `html:checkbox` で、初期値でチェックを入れた状態にしたいのですが、属性には初期値でチェックをいれた状態にするものがないように思います。

方法が分かる方がいましたら、ご教授お願いします。

```
<html:checkbox property="A" value="true" onchange="B( this.value )" >
    ﾁｪｯｸﾎﾞｯｸｽ
</html:checkbox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://tag.main.jp/htmlcheckbox.html
の中盤に説明があります。

フォームのBeanのpropertyの属性Aに
trueを設定して下さい。

Comment: 返答ありがとうございます。
こちらの方法で解決することが出来ました。

Answer (score 1):

少し古い記事ですが参考になりそうなページがありました。
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/chiheisen/20090707/1246980135

手元に環境がないため、動作確認ができず申し訳無いのですが、
ご参考になれば幸いです。

追記
----- リンク先から抜粋 (html:multibox) -----

```
public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
    if(request.getParameter("multi") == null){
        multi = null;
    }
    return super.validate(mapping, request);
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
参考に実装を進めてみます。